# Setting filepaths inside your .rb file when converted into an exe with ocra

Tags: ruby, exe, wxruby, ocra

I've had a lot of trouble getting one my wxruby scripts to use an image file I included in the exe with ocra.  If I didn't have the original image file in the same directory as the exe, the exe wouldn't find the image.

```
shape = File.join('warning3.png' )
```

I wanted the script to find the image I included in the exe.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Not really a question but an Answer, I couldn't find the answer anywhere so I thought I'd add it here so someone else have similar problems would fin the solution.  - I'll edit the question a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ocra [documentation](http://ocra.rubyforge.org/) it mentions `Dir.chdir File.dirname($0)` but I didn't get what it meant when it was mentioned.

If you need to use say an image file in your script you can make sure it works merely by having this `Dir.chdir(File.dirname($0))` line before you try to use any of your images.

For example in my app I'm using an image file and I couldn't get my exe to work if it wasn't in the same dir as the file but with the below it works anywhere so far.

```
Dir.chdir(File.dirname($0))
shape = File.join('warning3.png' )
```

I think this sets the script's current directory to the exe's directory inside it?  If I'm wrong please let me know!